# What are the names of the school(s) of economy that believe that printing enough money to be 100% sure price inflation always happen, is a bad thing?

Tags: inflation, deflation, schools-of-thought

What are the names of the school(s) of economy that believe that printing enough money (and spending) to be 100% sure price inflation always happen, is a bad thing?

Those schools must also be against demurrage.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any.

For overview of various historical schools of thought you can have look at:

Brue & Grant: The History of Economic Thought.

There is no historical school of thought in economics that would *simultaneously* believe that:

- printing money always, 100% of the time, leads to inflation.
- that inflation is always bad thing.
- imposing any tax on people with currency $x$ is always bad idea.

Comment: 1- The school of thought would not be anti tax, you can have tax as long its not demurrage (periodic tax for the fact the money is at your hand and not someone else hand/bank account)


 2- They would be against forcing price inflation trough money printing and spending that printed money. Printing money doesnt always cause inflation but because printing is made by the state, if printing B notes of current X (and spending them ) , is not enough to be 100% sure prince inflation will happen, they print not B notes, but B times N notes (a value that is big enough to cause price inflation)